# How to shim tinymce in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tinymce, webpack, shim

I'm trying to get [tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinymce) recognized by webpack. It sets a property named `tinymce` on `window`, so evidently one option is to `require()` it using syntax like this (described at the bottom of the [EXPORTING section](http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#exporting) of the webpack docs):

`require("imports?window=>{}!exports?window.XModule!./file.js`

But in this example, how is `./file.js` resolved? I installed tinymce via npm, and I can't figure out how to specify the right path to the `tinymce.js` file.

Regardless, I'd rather handle this in my configuration and be able to just `require('tinymce')` if possible, so I've installed `exports-loader` and added the following to my configuration (based on [this discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/192)):

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /[\/]tinymce\.js$/,
            loader: 'exports?tinymce'
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tinymce module on npm can't be required directly, but contains 4 different distributions of the library. Namely:

- `tinymce/tinymce.js`
- `tinymce/tinymce.min.js`
- `tinymce/tinymce.jquery.js`
- `tinymce/tinymce.jquery.min.js`

To be able to do `require('tinymce')` in your code, you can add [an alias](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) in your webpack config, as well as a custom loader for your distribution of choice.

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    // require('tinymce') will do require('tinymce/tinymce') 
    tinymce: 'tinymce/tinymce',
  },
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      // Only apply on tinymce/tinymce
      include: require.resolve('tinymce/tinymce'),
      // Export window.tinymce
      loader: 'exports?window.tinymce',
    },
  ],
},
```

Where you can replace `tinymce/tinymce` with your distribution of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now webpack is telling me `Cannot resolve module 'imports'` in the files where I `require('tinymce')`. I do have `imports-loader` installed, so I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: You might have to provide the full module names. `imports-loader?window=>{}!exports-loader?window.tinyMCE![dist]`

Comment: Yes, the full name of `imports-loader` worked: `tinymce: 'imports-loader?window=>{}!exports?window.tinymce!tinymce/tinymce.js'`

Comment: Although I'm not having the build problem anymore, I discovered today that tinymce is being imported as a function, and that it doesn't have any of the methods I'm expecting (such is the `init()` method for actually creating a WYSIWYG instance). How can I tell webpack to import tinymce as an object and retain all of its methods?

Comment: Could have sworn `resolve.alias` values supported loaders, but it appears they don't (see [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/268)). My previous suggestion caused `imports-loader` to be required on the client instead of tinymce. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I kept getting errors, no matter which way I tried to shim. Ended up using the cdn. That works

Answer (score 11):

Just like @cchamberlain I ended up using script loader for tinymce, but to load the plugins and other resources that were not required by default I used CopyWebpackPlugin instead of ES6 for more configurable solution.

```
var copyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
//...
  plugins: [
    new copyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './node_modules/tinymce/plugins', to: './plugins' },
      { from: './node_modules/tinymce/themes', to: './themes' },
      { from: './node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: './skins' }
    ])
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to integrate tinyMCE in my Angular 2/TypeScript based project by using the imports-loader and exports-loader and the copy-webpack-plugin.

First ensure that the necessary dependencies are available and part of the packages.json file of your project:

```
npm i tinymce --save
npm i exports-loader --save-dev
npm i imports-loader --save-dev    
npm i copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then add the required loader to the loaders-section of your webpack configuration:

```
    loaders: [          
        {
            test: require.resolve('tinymce/tinymce'),
            loaders: [
                'imports?this=>window',
                'exports?window.tinymce'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /tinymce\/(themes|plugins)\//,
            loaders: [
                'imports?this=>window'
            ]
        }]
```

To make the copyWebpackPlugin available in your webpack configuration, import it in the header part of the webpack configuration file:

```
var copyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
```

And, as Petri Ryhänen commented, add the following entry to the plugins-section of your webpack configuration:

```
plugins: [
    new copyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './node_modules/tinymce/plugins', to: './plugins' },
        { from: './node_modules/tinymce/themes', to: './themes' },
        { from: './node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: './skins' }
    ])
]
```

This step ensures that (required) addons of tinyMCE are also available in your webpack.

Finally to import tinyMCE in your Angular 2 component file, add

```
require('tinymce')

declare var tinymce: any;
```

to the import section and tinyMCE is ready to use.

Comment: Fantastic answer, it's working great.
Note, [now](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed) you need to write `'imports-loader?this=>window'`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work similar to how I bundle React to ensure I don't get two separate instances in DOM. I had some issues with imports / exports / expose loaders so instead I used script-loader.

In my setup I have a commons chunk that I use strictly for vendors (React / tinymce).

```
   entry: { 'loading': '../src/app/entry/loading'
          , 'app':  '../src/app/entry/app'
          , 'timeout': '../src/app/entry/timeout'
          , 'commons':  [ 'expose?React!react'
                        , 'expose?ReactDOM!react-dom'
                        , 'script!tinymce/tinymce.min.js'
                        ]
          }
```

This is working for me the same way that including the script from CDN would work however I now had errors because it could not find my themes / plugins / skins paths from my node_modules location. It was looking for them at paths `/assets/plugins`, `/assets/themes`, `/assets/skins` (I use webpack public path `/assets/`).

I resolved the second issue by mapping express to serve these two routes statically like so (es6):

```
  const NODE_MODULES_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  const TINYMCE_PLUGINS_ROOT = path.join(NODE_MODULES_ROOT, 'tinymce/plugins')
  const TINYMCE_THEMES_ROOT = path.join(NODE_MODULES_ROOT, 'tinymce/themes')
  const TINYMCE_SKINS_ROOT = path.join(NODE_MODULES_ROOT, 'tinymce/skins')

  router.use('/assets/plugins', express.static(TINYMCE_PLUGINS_ROOT))
  router.use('/assets/themes', express.static(TINYMCE_THEMES_ROOT))
  router.use('/assets/skins', express.static(TINYMCE_SKINS_ROOT))
```

After doing this `window.tinymce` / `window.tinyMCE` are both defined and functions same as CDN.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449894/3381938) (thanks to [Petri Ryhänen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5519328/petri-ryh%C3%A4nen)), I want to add my `copyWebpackPlugin` and `tinymce.init()` configuration adjustments.

```
new copyWebpackPlugin([{
  context: './node_modules/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
  from: './**/*',
  to: './tinymce/skin',
}]),
```

With this configuration you will get all skin files in `{output}/tinymce/skin` folder.

Then you can initialize tinymce like this:

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';

// A theme is also required
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme';  // you may change to 'inlite' theme

// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin';
// ... possibly other plugins

// Then anywhere in this file you can:
tinymce.init({
  // ... possibly other options
  skin_url: '/tinymce/skin',  // <-- !!! here we tell tinymce where
                              //         to load skin files from
  // ... possibly other options
});
```

With this I have both development and production builds working normally.

Answer (score 0):

We use TinyMCE jQuery 4.1.6 and the accepted answer did not work for us because `window` seems to be used in other locations by TinyMCE (e.g. window.setTimeout). Also, `document` not being shimmed seemed to cause problems.

This works for us:

```
alias: {
    'tinymce': 'tinymce/tinymce.jquery.js'
}

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /tinymce\/tinymce\.jquery\.js/,
            loader: 'imports?document=>window.document,this=>window!exports?window.tinymce'
        }
    ]
}
```

Load your plugins like this:

```
{
    test:  /tinymce\/plugins/,
    loader: 'imports?tinymce,this=>{tinymce:tinymce}'
}
```

Comment: I am not able to call the tinymce function on jQuery objects when using webpack. tinyMCE and tinymce are bound to window. I receive `$(...).tinymce is not a function` when trying to call tinymce on a jQuery object.